# My New Computer is Malfunctioning

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

This is weird!
I recently bought a brand new (but very cheap) computer, and there's something wrong with it.
I downloaded some MP3s onto it, and now every time I open my music program and try to create a playlist, the music program closes itself and my browser opens and displays the following lines:

1. $14_{10}13_{10}12_{10}13_{10}14_{10}14_{10}14_{10}/13_{10}13_{10}13_{10}/14_{10}(*)(*)/14_{10}13_{10}12_{10}13_{10}14_{10}14_{10}14_{10}14_{10}13_{10}13_{10}14_{10}13_{10}12_{10}$
2. $13_{10}$#$/13_{10}$#$/(*)(*)/(*)15_{10}15_{10}13_{10}10_{10}$#$12_{10}$
3. $15_{10}15_{10}13_{10}(*)15_{10}/13_{10}/15_{10}15_{10}13_{10}(*)15_{10}/13_{10}$
4. $13_{10}$#$ (*) 15_{10}13_{10}$#$12_{10}/10_{10}$#$/12_{10}/10_{10}$#$/12_{10}/13_{10}/13_{10}$#$(*)15_{10}13_{10}$#$12_{10}/10_{10}$#$/12_{10}/13_{10}/13_{10}$#
5. $(∗)/(∗)/(∗)10_{10}11_{10}/11_{10}10_{10}11_{10}12_{10}13_{10}/(∗)/13_{10}/11_{10}/(∗)/13_{10}12_{10}11_{10}10_{10}(∗)$
6. $(∗)(∗)13_{10}13_{10}14_{10}14_{10}13_{10}/12_{10}12_{10}11_{10}11_{10}{10_{10}10_{10}10_{10}10_{10}}(∗)$
7. $10_{10}$#$(∗)15_{10}13_{10}$#$15_{10}13_{10}$#$12_{10}10_{10}$#$(*)/10_{10}$#$(*)15_{10}13_{10}$#$13_{10}$#$13_{10}13_{10}$#$15_{10}$

(* = NaN)

Is this some sort of an error code or warning message?
What should I do?

Comment: Are the two dollar signs on line 4 supposed to be there?

Comment: @KoA Thank you, no, they're not. I've removed them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your computer is asking for:

> MORE RAM

If you

> Convert the numbers to their hex representation, you get what appear to be well-known melodies. Additionally, the asterisks are placeholders for G, which would make sense, as a 'G' would be $16_{10} = 10_{16}$ and not actually a 'G' symbol.

For example:

> The first line translates to EDCDEEE/DDD/E??/EDCDEEEEDDEDC which is the tune of Mary Had a Little Lamb, missing two notes (GG).

The full conversion:
1.

> EDCDEEE/DDD/E??/EDCDEEEEDDEDC - *Mary Had a Little Lamb*

2.

> D#/D#/??/?FFDA#C - *Oh Susanna (the last A should be A#)* ([Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)) *EDIT(Chowzen): fixed A# error (thanks Dan Russell!)*

3.

> FFD?F/D/FFD?F/D - *Ring Around the Rosie* ([ahorn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13191/ahorn) and [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell))

4.

> D#?FD#C/A#/C/A#/D/D#?FD#C/A#/C/D/D# *EDIT(Chowzen): Song is [Everybody do this](http://musicbus.com/resources/song-words/song-words-e/everybody-do-this/)*

5.

> ?/?/?AB/BABCD/?/D/B/?/DCBA? - *Row Your Boat*

6.

> ??DDEED/CCBBAAAA? - *The A.B.C.*

7.

> A#?FD#FD#CA#?/A#?FD#DD#F - *My Bonnie Lies over the Ocean*

---

Now if we

> Take the first letter of every song, we get MOR? RAM. Back solving, we can guess the 4th song is supposed to start with an E.

Comment: Very useful information! Does my stupid computer want me to play those songs or something?

Comment: Maybe it's mocking your taste in music or calling you a child :P

Comment: Certainly not! The computer, being logical to the extreme, would recognize that my taste in music is impeccable. :)

Comment: How is number 6 any of those songs suggested?

Comment: Number 2 has no key, and number 3 is ring a ring a rosy.

Comment: Number 2 looks like *Oh Susanna*, though the "A" should be "A#". Agree with @ahorn about number 3, Ring Around the Rosie. The four As in number 6 point to the Alphabet Song specifically. Not sure about #4...